# Compare two vectors

Tags: r

I need to compare to columns of data frame in order to find those rows which value in `column 2` is less than value in `column 1` by more than or equal to 8.

For example,

```
DF
V1   V2
10   2
20   29
30   21
40   60
```

The output, I would like to have is `3rd column` of zeros and ones:

```
DF
    V1   V2  V3
    10   2   1
    20   29  0
    30   21  1
    40   60  0
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DF$V3 <- ifelse(DF$V2 <= DF$V1-8, 1, 0)
 DF
 #   V1 V2 V3
 # 1 10  2  1
 # 2 20 29  0
 # 3 30 21  1
 # 4 40 60  0
```

Comment: mm im sorry, but your code assigns 1 to every pair of values where second column is less than first. But i need only those which are smaller by 8

Answer (score 4):

We can generate a boolean vector `TRUE/FALSE` for each row, with the value depending on whether the entry in column `V1` is larger than the corresponding entry in column `V2` by a value of at least 8. This boolean vector can be coerced into a numerical one (`1/0`) with `as.integer` or with the unary `+` operator placed in front of the logical expression.

```
DF$V3 <- as.numeric(DF$V1 >= (DF$V2 + 8))
#  V1 V2 V3
#1 10  2  1
#2 20 29  0
#3 30 21  1
#4 40 60  0
```

or

```
DF$V3 <- +(DF$V1 >= (DF$V2 + 8))
```